# How to combine multiple domains?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

Assume that I have 3 domains for a website.
one of the is the main domain.
eg:

1) abc.com (main domain)

2) myabc.com

3) abcmy.com

If want to arrange domains 2 and 3 such that when a user enters enters myabc.com or abcmy.com, he/she redirects to abc.com (the URL in browser must change to abc.com)

Can I use in by editing htaccess file?
(Plz assume that I cant use Addon Domains)

Programming language: PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this in your .htaccess using mod_rewrite.

This should do the trick:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myabc.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myabc.com$     [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.abcmy.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abcmy.com$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.abc.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, I used it, redirect is successful, But the main site doesnt load!!

Comment: What do you mean with "the main site doesn't load"?

Comment: Browsers loading bar doesnt stops (like being in an infinite loop), When I remove these codes from .htaccess file the website will load.

Comment: I think this should fix that, please try again